# Adding escape to String, possible?

Tags: java, unicode

Say I have a `String s = "50";`, and I want to append `"\u00"` onto the front of the string.

Is this possible without throwing an Illegal unicode escape?

Thanks.

Comment: `String s = 50` would not compile.

Comment: You mean `String s = "50";` ? Pls check your question after you have posted.

Comment: @suninsky Yes that is what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java, unicode escapes must be four digit. Use `\u0000`
Also `String s = 50`is invalid. Use `String s = "50"`

If you want the final result to be "\u0050", you have to realize that escapes only really exist at the source level. You'd have to do something like this to "append" the unicode modifier to the beginning of a String containing a number

```
s = new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(s,16));//16 because unicode is hex
```

Comment: I know, I am using pseudocode. I want the unicode vers of 50 by adding \u00 to the front of it.

Comment: @FriarBob see the edit... escapes cannot be manipulated at runtime, they are controlled by the compiler

Comment: So if one of my Unicode chars is 6e there is nothing I can do?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot there for a second that unicode is hex... silly me. use Integer.parseInt(s,16);